# MathJax on iPad

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I would like to be able to write HTML mathematics documents on my iPad without internet.

On my MacBook I use MathJax and it is excellent (using LaTex).

Answer (score 1):

The free app [MathMagic Lite for iOS by InfoLogic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mathmagic-lite-for-ios/id770212146?mt=8) may be helpful. Never used it, so I don’t know if it works well, but it has a 4-star rating.

*Disclaimer: no financial or other ties to developer InfoLogic.*